How to combine 2 plots (density and contour plots) into one plot?
I want to combine the density and contour plots in one plot like the following picture in the RStudio. I used the following code to create the two separate density and contour plots:
library(MASS)
library(plotly)   
set.seed(123)

lambda1 <- 4
k1      <- 3
theta1  <- 5
k2      <- 1
theta2  <- 5    
num_simulations <- 1000


n <- rpois(num_simulations, lambda1)
n_truncated <- n[n > 0]
num_simulations <- length(n_truncated)

generate_gamma_sums <- function(counts, k, theta) {
sapply(counts, function(x) sum(rgamma(x, shape = k, scale = theta)))
}

ssx <- data.frame(
sx = generate_gamma_sums(n_truncated, k1, theta1),
sy = generate_gamma_sums(n_truncated, k2, theta2)
)

colnames(ssx) <- c("X", "Y")

density_data <- kde2d(ssx$X, ssx$Y, n = 50)

x_vals <- rep(density_data$x, each = length(density_data$y))
y_vals <- rep(density_data$y, length(density_data$x))
z_vals <- as.vector(density_data$z)

xlim <- range(density_data$x)
ylim <- range(density_data$y)

pdf_3d_plot <- plot_ly(x = ~x_vals, y = ~y_vals, z = ~z_vals, type = 'mesh3d', intensity = ~z_vals,
               showscale = TRUE, colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("black", "white"))) %>%
  layout(
scene = list(
  xaxis = list(title = "X-axis", range = xlim, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE),
  yaxis = list(title = "Y-axis", range = ylim, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE),
zaxis = list(title = "Density", showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE),
 camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.2)) 
),
title = list(text = "3D PDF Surface", x = 0.5)
)

contour_2d_plot <- plot_ly(x = density_data$x, y = density_data$y, z = density_data$z,
                   type = "contour",
                   contours = list(coloring = "none", showlabels = TRUE),
                   line = list(color = 'black')) %>%

 layout(
xaxis = list(title = "X-axis", range = xlim, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE),
yaxis = list(title = "Y-axis", range = ylim, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE),
title = list(text = "2D Contour Plot", x = 0.5))

How to I combine plot 1 (pdf_3d_plot) and plot 2 (contour_2d_plot) into one?
Thanks


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885264/combining-3d-2d-plots

Yes, you can combine 2D & 3D in Plotly, but it requires finesse. However, in the case of your example, half the code you've painstakingly written is not necessary. You can plot the output of kde2d and use the argument, contours = list(z = list(show = T)) in the trace type = surface. (No mesh or contour trace needed - it's all in one.) To add more contours, add more axis tick marks. For example, layout(scene = list(zaxis = list(nticks = 15))) will ensure that there are 15 contours in either or both the projection or show on the z axis.

The question has been reopened, @Kat, you should post your comment as an answer.

Since your question was reopened (thanks @Dour High Arch), I thought I'd provide a complete answer to your question.
As I stated in my comment, combining a surface and contours if relatively easy.
I only used your code up to the line
density_data <- kde2d(ssx$X, ssx$Y, n = 50)

None of the other code was necessary to create the plot.
If you have any questions, let me know.
plot_ly(x = density_data$x, y = density_data$y, z = density_data$z,
        type = "surface", contours = list(z = list(show = T, project = list(z = T)))) %>% 
  layout(scene = list(zaxis = list(nticks = 15), # to create 15 contour levels
                      camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.75, y = .9, z = -.2))))


